# Tabulator Show/Hide Groups

Tags: tabulator

Is there any way to show/hide the GroupBy?  I like the option to collapse or expand groups, but it would be nice to collapse/expand/no-grouping as 3 options.

How could I add a button to show/hide the groups? Where would I place the code to do a function like this?

Answer (score 2):

Passing falsy values or nothing at all to `tabulator.setGroupBy()` effectively disables grouping:

```
var tabulator = new Tabulator({});
var groupBy = tabulator.options.groupBy;

disableGroupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tabulator.setGroupBy();
});

enableGroupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tabulator.setGroupBy(groupBy);
});
```

To expand/collapse groups, you will need:

```
expandGroupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tabulator.setGroupStartOpen(true)
  tabulator.getGroups().forEach(x => x._group.show())
});

collapseGroupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tabulator.setGroupStartOpen(false)
  tabulator.getGroups().forEach(x => x._group.hide())
});
```

Note that the performance of expand/collapse groups may be bad when you have lots of row groups.

See http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/group for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$("#show-all-group").click(function(){
    table.setGroupStartOpen(true);
});
```

documentation: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/group

Answer (score 0):

To quickly expand (and collapse), you can use this:

```
$("#group-button").on("click", function(){
    let oldGroup = table.options.groupBy;
    table.setGroupStartOpen(!table.options.groupStartOpen);
    
    if (table.options.groupStartOpen)
        $("#group-button").text("Collapse");
     else $("#group-button").text("Expand");
    
    table.setGroupBy("some_other_field");
    table.setGroupBy(oldGroup);
});
```

- `some_other_field`: Just name of the field you never use for grouping; this is necessary in order to force the Tabulator to redraw the groupings. I am using a hidden field for this purpose. And then we just restore old `groupBy`.
- `table`: Your tabulator object.
- `group-button`: The id of the collapsed (or expanded) button.

Tabulator version: 5.2

Comment: Looks like a good solution to try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The forEach methods from the previous answers have not worked for me, here is the approach that works to toggle the expanded/collapsed state of groups:

```
let groups_expanded = false;

function toggle_groups() {
    groups_expanded = !groups_expanded;
    table.setGroupStartOpen(groups_expanded);
    for (let i = 0; i < table.getGroups().length; i++) {
        groups_expanded ? table.getGroups()[i].show() : table.getGroups()[i].hide();
    }
};
```